# HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync is not working for NodusPayFabric Xamrin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, httpwebrequest, portable-class-library

**Purpose**: I am creating here a method which generates the token for payment gateway.

Code to generate and get the response from Nodus Payfabric is in **PCL** and the same code is working for **Xamarin.IOS** but not for **Xamarin.Android**.

The method is as below:

```
public async Task<HttpWebResponse> GetWebResponseForSecurityToken(string deviceID)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://sandbox.payfabric.com/v2/rest/api/token/create") as HttpWebRequest;
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.Headers["authorization"] = deviceID;
        return await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse; // ISSUE LINE
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As mentioned in above method issue is in ***return*** line which is not generating any error or returning the response, instead debug mode is closed after executing this line.

Is there anything I am missing to support this code with **Xamarin.Android**?